# How to make JOLT return key value as a list even it has a single value or multi-value?

Tags: json, jolt

I want to convert JSON format to another format so I use jolt for that. please if there is best from jolt recommend me to it.

when I map this object

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "sd4s5d4",
  "phone": "111",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

the expected output is ok the value of groups is returned as a list

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "username": "sd4s5d4",
 "phone": "111",
 "groups": [ 1, 2 ]
}
```

but when I map this object

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "username": "sd4s5d4",
  "phone": "111",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

it returns

```json
{
  "id": 5,
  "username": "sd4s5d4",
  "phone": "111",
  "groups": 1 
}
```

how to make groups in last output to be list even if it one item.
wanted format

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "username": "sd4s5d4",
  "phone": "111",
  "groups": [1]
}
```

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "username": "username",
      "phone": "phone",
      "groups": {
        "*": {
          "id": "groups"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replacing `"id": "groups"` with `"id": "groups.[&1]"` is enough, btw no need to repeat every element individually, just replace them with proper substitution by using ampersand operator prepended to the integer values which represent the level that provide to the target key (e.g.number of `}` operators while arriving the related key). So, convert `"id": "groups.[&1]"`  to `"id": "&2.[&1]"`, and use `"*": "&",` for the other elements such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "groups": {
        "*": {
          "id": "&2.[&1]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: what is &2 and [&1] mean exactly?

Comment: Hi @AlyAhmedMohamed akh, `&2` represents going two levels up (eg. traversing  `}` sign twice) to reach the key `groups`, and `&1` stands for representing the indexes(in this case sub-objects) of the `groups` list(notice that you're going one level up to reach to asterisk).  The square brackets wrapping `&1` up forces to make that a list.